# Mongoengine connecting to atlas No replica set members found yet

Tags: python, pymongo, uwsgi, mongodb-atlas

after a working production app was connected to local mongo, we've decided to move to `Mongo Atlas`. 
This caused production errors.

```
Our stack is docker -> alping 3.6 -> python 2.7.13 -> Flask -> uwsgi (2.0.17) -> nginx running on aws
flask-mongoengine-0.9.3 mongoengine-0.14.3 pymongo-3.5.1
```

when starting the app in `staging/production`, The `uwsgi` is sending `No replica set members found yet`.

We don't know why.

We've tried different connection settings `connect: False` which is lazy connecting, meaning not on initializing, but on first query. 
It caused the nginx to fail for `resource temporarily unavailable` error on some of our apps. We had to restart multiple times for the app to finally start serving requests.

I think the issue is with pymongo and the fact that it's not `fork-safe` 
http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html?highlight=thread#id3
and `uwsgi` is using forks

I suspect it might be related to the way my app is being initalized.
might by aginst [Using PyMongo with Multiprocessing](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#using-pymongo-with-multiprocessing)
here is the app init code:

```
from app import FlaskApp
from flask import current_app

app = None

from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

import logging

application, app = init_flask_app(app_instance, module_name='my_module')


def init_flask_app(app_instance, **kwargs):
    app_instance.init_instance(environment_config)

    application = app_instance.get_instance()
    app = application.app
    return application, app 

# app_instance.py
import FlaskApp
def init_instance(env):
    global app
    app = FlaskApp(env)
    return app


def get_instance():
    if globals().get('app') is None:
        app = current_app.flask_app_object
    else:
        app = globals().get('app')

    assert app is not None
    return app




class FlaskApp(object):

    def __init__(self, env):
        .....

        # Initialize the DB
        self.db = Database(self.app)
        ....
        # used in app_instance.py to get the flask app object in case it's None
        self.app.flask_app_object = self    

    def run_server(self):
        self.app.run(host=self.app.config['HOST'], port=self.app.config['PORT'], debug=self.app.config['DEBUG'])



class Database(object):

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.db = MongoEngine(app)

    def drop_all(self, database_name):
        logging.warn("Dropping database %s" % database_name)
        self.db.connection.drop_database(database_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run_server()
```

help in debugging this will be appreciated!

Comment: Remove the earlier comments, so we can keep it clean. Does moving the `application, app = init_flask_app(app_instance, module_name='my_module')` inside main helps in anyway?

Comment: It’s a shared helper function

Comment: Have you tried running it with gunicorn also?

Comment: No, that’s out of my hands. It’s an infra change . I rather focus on the wusgi solution

Comment: @WebQube have you reached any solution for this error?

Comment: I don't actually. I'm pretty sure it was but I don't have access to the code by now\